# Nearly everything is white while rendering. (Blender) Even if its not white its because of lighting

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

So i was going to make a humanoid creature for my team's game. I just wanted to show how far i came in a hour to my team, when i rendered it, background became white, my humanoid object became 2D gray. That was where everything started. First photo shows how it had to look like[image: How it must look like]

And second photo shows what i get when i render it
[image: What i get]

That was not the end, it happens to everything, i don't know why.
File: [image]
[image: What i need]
[image: What i get lol]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ... looks like shading and rendering.. share, and there will probably be a quick fix.

Comment: @moonboots i did

Comment: @RobinBetts i shared the file if its what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in *Solid Preview* mode, your scene will appear grey by default, with a dark background and no material:

[image]

If you switch to *Rendered Preview* mode (the mode that will give you a preview of what your render will look like), your background will be determined by the *World* color and strength (for the moment it's white), the lighting will be determined by the background and the lights (you have one light, increase its strength or move it close to your object, otherwise it won't light it), and the object surface will depend on the material you've assigned to it (it's pure white as well for the moment):

[image]

If you want to change the world settings, you need to open the *World* panel, or open the *Shader Editor* window, switch it from *Object* to *World*, enable the *Use Nodes* option, change the *Backgound* node settings (*Color, Strength*, plug an HDRI if necessary):

[image]

Comment: While following what you wrote, i realised its happening because scene world. I'm in viewport and see the exact thing in render. How can i disable scene world? I already clicked at "Scene world" box but it only changes viewport not render, if i can't change it what else i can do? Thanks in advice.

Comment: For the render itself, disabling Scene World won't change anything, you need to open the World panel, or open the Shader Editor window, switch it from Object to World, enable the Use Nodes option, change the Backgound node settings (color, strength, plug an HDRI if necessary)

Comment: After sometime i played with options, its seems like when i make value of color darker it turns visible but if its at max or nearby it turns exactly same with background color

Comment: @Sycho_Zer0SYCH Well, yes that's what moonboots explained to you. If you have a completely white object and it is surrounded by a completely white world (meaning it's shining white light on it), what else than white on white dou you expect it to look like? I guess you should really spend some time watching tutorials on materials and the shader editor as well as lighting setups.